# IOS: send a mail without iphone/ipad mail app

Tags: ios, xcode, email

I want to create an app that have 5 textfield and a textView:

```
1 - Name
2 - Surname
3 - Telephone
4 - "your email" (user email, not address email receiver)
5 - city
6 - textView (for body mail)
```

So, when I filled all textView I want to send this message at an address mail that is set in the code.

I'll compose mail as this example:

```
mail from: "name" "surmane"
email: "yuor email"
telephone: "telephone"
city: "city"
bosy: "textview content""
```

But it's not my problem; my problem is that I don't want to use app mail iphone, but I want that when I push a button "send", I want to show just an alertView that say "email sent"; is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailSendingController = [MFMailComposeViewController new];

[mailSendingController setSubject:@"Feedback"];
[mailSendingController setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"feedback@us.com"]];
[mailSendingController setMessageBody:myText isHTML:NO];

mailSendingController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[self presentModalViewController:mailSendingController animated:YES];
```

where myText is a string that you make with your info

Answer (score 0):

This could be done by sending the data to a server and sending it from there. I dont see a way of sending it directly from the device without using the mail app.

Comment: No dude, you solve this by creating a webservice like hiren said. Send some data to a php server for example through POST, and fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 0):

for this you have to create webservice. because without this the only option is inbuilt mail method of ios