# Send email in iOS application

Tags: ios, email

I'm working on an app but I need one last thing. I would like to send an in-app mail with the data from several textfields. I store the data like this:

```
 //1e savestring
NSString *saveString59 = field1.text;
NSUserDefaults *defaults59 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults59 setObject:saveString59 forKey:@"saveString59"];
[defaults59 synchronize];
```

and I display it like this:

```
//First load string
NSUserDefaults *defaults59 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loadString59 = [defaults59 objectForKey:@"saveString59"];
[field1 setText:loadString59];
[loaded setText:@"Data Loaded Successfully" ];
```

I would like to display this in my email in a particular way. It's a tennis app and each player has some aces and some first serves.

Can I display the data in-mail like this?

Name of player (textfield1)

> Aces: "data" (textfield2) 
>   First serves: "data" (textfield3) 
>   Seconds serves: "data" etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOS: send a mail without iphone/ipad mail app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602007/ios-send-a-mail-without-iphone-ipad-mail-app)

Comment: So, is your problem formatting the data or sending the email?

Comment: look this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274538/send-email-without-gui/45283096#45283096

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using MFMailComposeViewController with an HTML formatted body. To get your textfield data into the body you can use something similar to this:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p>Name of player %@</p>", self.textField1.text];                          
[mail setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];
```

Comment: Thnx for your help, but you give me the possibility of adding 1 textfield data to my mail, but I need about 15 textfield data added to my mail...

Comment: To achieve this you can add them all to the NSString with the stringWithFormat function like this: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p>Name of player %@</p><p>Aces: %@</p>", self.textField1.text, self.textField2.text]. For better readability I would suggest to use an NSMutableString and use the appendFormat function.

Answer (score -1):

Use `MFMailComposeViewController`.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8602007/ios-send-a-mail-without-iphone-ipad-mail-app?rq=1) answer for more help.

Edit: Reference doc for this class can help you too:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html

HTH.